# Migrating from angularjs select to selectize empty value

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

Currently I use angularjs select directive, I have a choice to reset to None value

```
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="selectOptions">
  <option value="">None</option>
</select>
```

When I select the None option myModel is null

```
{{ myModel === null }} // true
```

I want to have the same behaviour with angularjs selectize so I am adding an option with "" value.

```
onInitialize: function(selectize) {
  selectize.addOption({id: '', name: 'None'});
}
```

So when I choose none with selectize my model is an empty string and not null

```
{{ myModel === null }} // false
```

How can I change this to null ?
Is it possible to do it without writing a new directive ?

Comment: Why do you need it to be `null`? Why not compare with empty string? Or any other meaningless value that indicates that it is the default?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to `id` value `null`, `0` (*zero*) or let it `undefined` like this:

```
onInitialize: function(selectize) {
  selectize.addOption({id: null, name: 'None'});
  // selectize.addOption({id: 0, name: 'None'});
  // selectize.addOption({name: 'None'});
}
```

and check it like this:

```
{{ !myModel }}
```

---

As an alternate solution you could just check against the `''` (*empty value*) like this:

```
{{ myModel === '' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way by extending the plugin on

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', setSelectizeValue);

var setSelectizeValue = function() {
    if(scope.ngModel === '') {
      scope.ngModel=null;
    }
```

Still looking for a way without extending the plugin.